# Comparison principle for heat equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g:\bar \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous (non-constant) function.

Where can I find a proof of the fact that if $u$ solves 
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_t + \Delta u = 0 &\quad \text{ on } (0,\infty) \times \Omega \\
u = 0  &\quad \text{ on } (0,\infty) \times \partial \Omega \\
u(0,\cdot) =g  &\quad \text{ on }   \bar \Omega  
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

then 
$$\min_{\bar \Omega} g < u(t,x) <\max_{\bar \Omega} g$$
for any $t>0$ and $x \in \bar \Omega$?

Answer (score 1):

This is the maximum principle for the heat equation which says solutions to the heat equation attains its maximum and minimum on the boundary of $\Omega$ or at time $t=0$. Every PDE book worth its salt should cover this property in its discussion of the heat equation. [Here is a proof in a single spatial variable](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~bryan/lottamath/heatmaxprin.pdf).